# What is the name of this algorithm flow notation?

Tags: algorithm, terminology, notation, flow-diagram

I found this in my programing notes and could not find references to the algorithm flow diagram on the right. What is the name of this notation ?

[image: algorithm flow with blocks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **structogram** or  **Nassi–Shneiderman diagram**.

For more information have a look at the respective [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structogram).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [Nassi-Shneiderman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassi%E2%80%93Shneiderman_diagram) diagram to me.